# All contacts lost on Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro, how to find a reason? "Deleted on Sprd - ums512_1h10_Natv"

Tags: contacts, google-account, xiaomi

I’m an iPhone user myself, so I am not well familiar with how Google and simultaneous Xiaomi backup management.

My father who has Xiaomi Redmi Note 8 Pro told me all his contacts are missing. I’ve tried to restore the contacts on the phone, but Xiaomi backup management wasn’t even loading (showing errors at "loading backup 0%"). I wasn't able to find Google Contacts at all on the phone.

I took a route of logging in to my father’s Google account on the web browser and then proceed to contacts.google.com where I could see all his contacts in trash and the **"reason" was listed as "Deleted on Sprd - ums512_1h10_Natv"**. I was able to restore all the contacts from trash (thankfully) and immediately after restoring the contacts there on contacts.google.com the contacts appeared on the phone.

I am googling this message and see some traces of similar problems with contacts but nothing that looks useful.

How could I find out what app, system component or a setting could cause the contacts to be deleted? And how could I configure my father’s phone to prevent this problem in the future? Loosing contacts is a real horror story.

Thank you!

Comment: Quick research on `ums512_1h10_Natv` revealed that this is a Tesla Style Head Unit. I could only guess that someone (accidentally) deleted all the contacts from the vehicle which is linked to your father's Google account. This is because Google is a sync solution but not really a backup solution, meaning that actions done on one account will be synced to all devices linked to that account.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting – my father is on a vacation visiting me and his car is back in where they live. He did have some problems with the media system in the car, which is actually a "Tesla Style" big flat screen, and definitely did sync the phone with the system. Interesting how could this be prevented in future, while using such a system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is a faulty Infotainment system from Joying – https://forum-joyingauto.com/showthread.php?tid=3629 apparently an old issue with this system.

Would be nice from Google to assign some source of data like the main one and not respect all connected devices with the same priority.